# Return count of relation along with parent data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello i have two tables in my database:

1. categories
2. events

I have a page that displays a list of all categories.  However i want to display a count of how many events are in each category next to the category title.
eg.:

1. comedy (10)
2. music (5)

The relationship between these two models is **one to many**, as **one** category can have **zero or more** events.

My question is how do i fetch the total number of events for each category along with the category data when i execute this code:

```
$categories = Category::get();
```

**What i have tried so far:**

```
class Categories extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{
    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'name',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
        'on_update'  => true,
    ];

    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function events() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Events', 'category_id');
    }

    public function eventsCountRelation() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Events', 'category_id')->selectRaw('id, count(*) as count');
    }

    public function eventsCountAttribute() {
        return $this->eventsCountRelation->count();
    }
}
```

**The error i get:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($categories as $categoriy) {
    echo $category->name.' ('.$category->events->count().')';
}
```

Returns something like:
    comedy (10)
    music (5)

If you want to print it in a view you don't need to load them in the controller.
But if you want to print it as json you need something like this:

```
$categories = Category::all();
```

In the Category Model you need to add this:

```
protected $appends = ['counter'];

public function getCounterAttribute() {
    return $this->events->count();
}
```

Update your class like this:

```
class Categories extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{
    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'name',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
        'on_update'  => true,
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'counter'
    ];

    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function events() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Events', 'category_id');
    }

    public function eventsCounterAttribute() {
        return $this->events->count();
    }
}
```

You don't need more.

Comment: I really want to avoid using a foreach loop as much as possible.

Comment: You need the foreach loop to print your categories. Not for the counter

Comment: The data is being returned as JSON

Comment: then you need the secound part of the answer. The appends variable will add the `counter` of the events to your category object. You can call it with `category->counter;`

Comment: When i try that i get the same error i just posted in my post.

Comment: `eventsCountAttribute` is wrong. it has to be `getCountAttribute` to be callable as $category->count

Comment: Wow okay that finally worked, thank you very much, i think i get it now!! :)

Comment: Good :) For more details check the official documentation, it's very detailed.